# Reading a string, ignoring white space and replacing punctuation

Tags: c

I am looking to see if it's possible to get user input with whitespace and punctuation and remove the whitespace, and then replace the punctuation.

As an example, first and last name

```
#define MAXLEN = 10
char name[MAXLEN+1];
printf("Enter first name, last name: "); //e.g., Tom , Sno
scanf("%c", name)
Output: Tom ,  Snow
Desired output: Tom Snow
```

I'm not sure how I would remove the whitespaces or replace the punctuation, any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: loop down the string copying the characters you want to a new string , dropping those that you dont want

Comment: PS, your example is > 10 characters

Comment: @pm100 didnt see that, will fix

Comment: `%c` reads a single character, not a string.

Comment: And `%s` would only read `"Tom"`. It might be more helpful to think of the task as "remove all whitespace and punctuation and separate the parts that remain with a single space."

Comment: Doing basic research is always a good thing before asking a question. Type in "C remove white space from string" into your favourite search engine. Even if you don't find an exact answer surely you will find more than enough to progress.

Comment: to read a whole line use fgets

Comment: @stark or getline

Comment: @pm100: The function `getline` is not part of ISO C. It is a platform-specific function.

Answer (score 0):

Your question reads like a CS homework assignment which is likely going to be looked at warily by most responders here.  We don't want to do your homework for you because that might not help you learn. So instead of providing specific code, I'll just ask a couple of questions that may hopefully help you think out the steps that should lead you in a good direction.

I'm also assuming a newcomer's level of programming knowledge.  Apologies if I ask something too basic or in a way that doesn't make sense.

- While it makes sense to want to literally remove whitespace from and replace punctuation in the string you were provided from your input, can you instead build a new string that contains the same data in `name` but without whitespace and with replaced punctuation?
- In order to remove the whitespace, you will need to see if each character is whitespace (however you need to define the term).
- In order to replace punctuation, you will need to see if each character is punctuation.  And in its place, you'll need to put something else.